# How to read JSON file into avro mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I am trying to write a mapreduce job for hadoop using avro. The goal is to load the json files with avro and then run some reducers on it.

Since I want to reduce it in mapreduce and it should run efficiently, I don't want to convert the json file on the disk to an avro file before running the job.

Unfortunately I get the following error:

`Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to class org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey (org.apache.hadoop.io.Text and org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey are in unnamed module of loader 'app'`

WordCount.java

```java
package mz;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroValue;
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroJob;
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyValueOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends
            Mapper<AvroKey<Review>, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private final static IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);

        @Override
        public void map(AvroKey<Review> key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            String category = key.datum().getCategory().toString();
            String reviewText = key.datum().getReviewText().toString();

            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(reviewText);
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                context.write(new Text(category + ":" + itr.nextToken()), ONE);
            }

        }
    }

    public static class CountReducer extends
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, AvroKey<CharSequence>, AvroValue<Integer>> {

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                           Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            context.write(new AvroKey<>(key.toString()), new AvroValue<>(sum));
        }
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: mz.MapReduceColorCount <input path> <output path>");
            return -1;
        }

        Job job = new Job(getConf());
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setJobName("Color Count");

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, Review.getClassSchema());
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroKeyValueOutputFormat.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CountReducer.class);
        AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));
        AvroJob.setOutputValueSchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.INT));

        return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

Review.avsc

```json
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Review",
  "namespace" : "mz",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "reviewerID",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "asin",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "reviewerName",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "helpful",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : "long"
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "reviewText",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "overall",
    "type" : "double"
  }, {
    "name" : "summary",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "unixReviewTime",
    "type" : "long"
  }, {
    "name" : "reviewTime",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "category",
    "type" : "string"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

KeyValueTextInputFormat requires Map input to be (Text, Text) tuples, which are split apart within the file by tab character, by default.

Therefore, trying to read the input with AvroKey class is incorrect, and you'll need to use a different InputFormat if that's what you want. Otherwise, you say you're reading JSON files, so your mapper input would not be Avro, it would actually be Text

Besides, that, I'd strongly suggest using Spark for reading/writing JSON and Avro since MapReduce doesn't come with strong JSON support